# Difference between a Target and a Bundle in iOS?

Tags: ios

I have been doing some research on targets, bundles and the layout of iOS applications. I'm  trying to understand all of the pre-created resources in the application bundle. What is the relationship between a target and a bundle? Is a target just the executable of all the resources contained in a bundle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bundle is a package of resources, contains images, plists, etc.  A target is a specific set of settings and files that produce a particular type of build, i.e. a Debug build, a Distribution build, a build only for Simulator, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Application bundle and target both are different . Bundle carries all resources files necessary for ur app n target takes care of the configurations.